# How to integrate a third party plugin which is available in Eclipse in my RCP application?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, rcp

How can I integrate a third party plugin which is available in Eclipse in my RCP application?

There is  view in Eclipse called "team artifacts". I already created an RCP. Now I want this view in my RCP, too. I tried to add using view extension, but when right clicking most of the sub menus visible in Eclipse are not visible in my RCP. How is that possible? Am I missing something or jars or any settings?

Comment: This is too broad. You need to look at the plug-in to see how it declares the menus, what its dependencies are, ....

Comment: if the plugin is already integrated within the eclipse, when i export my RCP from the same eclipse, it should automatically show all the options right? or do i need to externally specify which sub menus only i want?

Comment: No, the plugin may be set to only show things on particular views or perspectives or many other things. You have to look at how it is set up to understand what it does.